# Efficiently inserting a slice into another slice

Tags: go, slice

In Go you can insert a slice into the middle of another slice [like this](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks):

```
a = append(a[:i], append(b, a[i:]...)...)
```

However, as I understand it that will first append `a[i:]` to `b` by copying it to the end of `b` (and potentially reallocating `b`, and *then* copy that whole slice to `a`, again potentially reallocating it.

This seems like there is an extra copy and allocation to what you really need. In C++ I'd do it something like this (I mean... without using `insert` obviously).

```
// Reserve enough space in `a` for `a` and `b`.
a.reserve(a.size() + b.size());

// Move the second half of `a` to the end.
std::copy(a.begin() + i, a.end(), a.begin() + i + b.size());

// Copy `b` into the middle.
std::copy(b.begin(), b.end(), a.begin() + i);
```

Is there a similar way to do this in Go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a translation to Go assuming a slice of int:

```
// Reserve space for the combined length of the slices
c := make([]int, len(a)+len(b))

// Copy the first part of a to the beginning
copy(c, a[:i])

// Copy the last part of a to the end
copy(c[i+len(b):], a[i:])

// Copy b to the middle
copy(c[i:], b)
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/HBNPuJRvc9)

To take advantage of `a`'s capacity, do this:

```
if cap(a) < len(a)+len(b) {
    // Not enough space, allocate new slice
    c := make([]int, len(a)+len(b))

    // Copy the first part of a to the beginning
    copy(c, a[:i])

    // Copy the last part of a to the end
    copy(c[i+len(b):], a[i:])

    a = c
} else {
    // reslice to combined length
    a = a[:len(a)+len(b)]

    // copy the last part of a to the end
    copy(a[i+len(b):], a[i:])

}
// copy b to the middle
copy(a[i:], b)
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/xXxFVEa6vB)